# how to check checkbox event dynamically created in javascript using jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here I am getting values from sqlite db,binding those values in javascript and showing it on html by calling id of that particular .In this process I reuired to put checkbox.I created it in javascript only not in html. so now i required to check the checkbox in dynamically created javascript. here I am pasting my code. Thanks in advance for your valuable suggestions.

```
$('#lightsList').append('<li style="background:#666666">'+
            '<img src="../images/' + light.ledLightImage + '" class="ui-li-thumb" style="margin-left: 10px; margin-top:2px;"/>' +
            '<form id="checkbox" style="padding-top:18px; color:#ffffff">'+
            '<input type="checkbox" name="Tick" value="Tick" class="regular-checkbox" onclick="checked()"/><br>Tick'+
            '</form>' +
            '<p class="line1">' + light.ledLightName  + '</p>' +
            '</li>'+
            '<li style="display:none;">'+light.ledWattage+'</li>');
```

Comment: Do u want to bind check event of dynamically added checkboxes?

Comment: Then follow any of the answer below. It will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on) for [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) like,

```
$('#lightsList').on('click', '.regular-checkbox', function() {
    checked();// call your function checked here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).on('change', '.regular-checkbox', function() {
    // event handler
});
```